# PHP shell exec command

Tags: php, shell, exec

I am using a windows application tesseract, long story short this is an OCR application which runs through command.

After installing the application i used command to test and works fine using this line:

```
tesseract text.png out
```

It practically gets the image and outputs to text file out.txt

I even changed directory and is accessible from everywhere.

Now the problem comes when using php i am using the code as follows:

```
echo exec("tesseract text.png out 2>&1", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

And this time instead of getting the file it is saying that tesseract is not recognized!

This is the output:

```
operable program or batch file.
C:\wamp64\www\prestashop\ocr\ocr.php:12:
array (size=4)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string 'C:\wamp64\www\prestashop\ocr>tesseract text.png out'    (length=51)
  2 => string ''tesseract' is not recognized as an internal or external command,' (length=65)
  3 => string 'operable program or batch file.' (length=31)
```

Can anyone help me please!?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer. I don't know why but i had to restart the PC to get it to work with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Seem that windows environment variable `PATH` is not set.

Try to reset `PATH`

```
echo exec("PATH %PATH% && tesseract text.png out 2>&1", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Or set `PATH` value from parent session

```
echo exec("PATH ".getenv('PATH')." && tesseract text.png out 2>&1", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Hope this will help